# Testing that I have connected to a particular signal in Django

Tags: python, django, testing

I have a Django app called "publisher", it connects to various signals in my django project, and when it receives them it sends a message to a rabbitmq queue. What I want to do is to be able to test that my setup code is connecting to the correct signals.

My app structure looks like:

```
publisher
    - __init__.py
    - signals.py
    - tests.py
```

my __init__.py looks like:

```
import signals
```

and my signals.py:

```
def receiver_function(*args, **kwargs):
    #Does rabbitmq stuff

my_interesting_signal.connect(receiver_function)
```

I has thought about patching the receiver function, and checking that the mock was called when I sent the signal:

tests.py:

```
class SignalsTeste(TestCase):

    def_test_connection(self):

        with patch('publisher.signals.receiver_function') as receiver_mock:
            my_interesting_signal.application_created.send(None)
            self.assertEquals(receiver_mock.call_count, 1)
```

However because the signals module is imported, and therefore the signal connections are made before the tests are run, this approach doesn't work as the connections are made before the function is patched......

Can anyone suggest an alternative strategy?

Comment: I don't know if I get this straight but I track my signals writing to a log in the receiver function def receiver_function(*args, **kwargs):

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I ran into the same mocking problem you describe. My solution is to reach into Django's signal registry and assert that my function was registered with the correct signal.

Here's my test:

```
def test_signal_registry(self):
    from foo.models import bar_func  # The function I want to register.
    from django.db.models import signals
    registered_functions = [r[1]() for r in signals.pre_delete.receivers]
    self.assertIn(bar_func, registered_functions)
```

A little explanation about that list comprehension:

"pre_delete" is the instance of django.dispatch.dispatcher.Signal that I cared about in this case. You would be using your own "my_interesting_signal" in your example. Signals have an internal property called "receivers" that's a list of two-tuples, where the second element is a weakref to the function you register (hence r[1]). Calling a weakref returns the referent.

I had to play around with weakrefs to figure that much out:

```
import weakref
def foo():
    pass
w = weakref.ref(foo)
w() == foo
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think this is quite right.  If bar_func is in `models.py` then, yes, that will be automatically imported by Django and therefore connected to the signal.  But if it's in a `signals.py` then it won't necessarily.  Also, the act of importing your receiever within the test will automatically connect it, so the test will pass even if you aren't connecting it elsewhere.

Comment: @seddonym very good points, but technically you should always be using an `AppConfig` to register the signals (or doing the imports), so I guess you can safely assume that at least that is happening.  So maybe another test to make sure AppConfig registers your receivers?

Comment: Not a bad idea!

Answer (score 5):

A way to test if the signal is connected is disconnecting it and checking the result of this action. Calling `<some_signal>.disconnect(...)` returns `True` if the signal was disconnected or `False` if not.

For example we want to test that the `post_save` signal is connected to our `receiver_function`.

modules.py

```
def receiver_function(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

signals.post_save.connect(receiver_function)
```

tests.py

```
class SignalsTest(TestCase):
    def test_connection(self):
        result = signals.post_save.disconnect(receiver_function)

        self.assertTrue(result)
```

The call to `disconnect` must use the same arguments that the `connect` call(`sender`, `dispatch_uid`)

*It's is necessary to connect the signal again after the test, if not it will remain disconnected*

Answer (score 1):

This is quite tricky, because as you say, if you mock or import anything from the file you include the receiver in, you automatically connect it.  This is across your *entire test suite* and not just in the test file in question.  Here's a snippet you can use, but you need to be disciplined in following the comments regarding avoiding imports in the receivers file.

```
from django.test import TestCase

class ReceiverConnectionTestCase(TestCase):
    """TestCase that allows asserting that a given receiver is connected
    to a signal.

    Important: this will work correctly providing you:
        1. Do not import or patch anything in the module containing the receiver
           in any django.test.TestCase.
        2. Do not import (except in the context of a method) the module
           containing the receiver in any test module.

    This is because as soon as you import/patch, the receiver will be connected
    by your test and will be connected for the entire test suite run.

    If you want to test the behaviour of the receiver, you may do this
    providing it is a unittest.TestCase, and there is no import from the
    receiver module in that test module.

    Usage:

        # myapp/receivers.py
        from django.dispatch import receiver
        from apples.signals import apple_eaten
        from apples.models import Apple

        @receiver(apple_eaten, sender=Apple)
        def my_receiver(sender, **kwargs):
            pass


        # tests/integration_tests.py
        from apples.signals import apple_eaten
        from apples.models import Apple

        class TestMyReceiverConnection(ReceiverConnectionTestCase):
            def test_connection(self):
                self.assert_receiver_is_connected(
                    'myapp.receivers.my_receiver',
                    signal=apple_eaten, sender=Apple)

    """
    def assert_receiver_is_connected(self, receiver_string, signal, sender):
        receivers = signal._live_receivers(sender)
        receiver_strings = [
            "{}.{}".format(r.__module__, r.__name__) for r in receivers]
        if receiver_string not in receiver_strings:
            raise AssertionError(
                '{} is not connected to signal.'.format(receiver_string))
```

This works because Django runs `django.test.TestCase` before `unittest.TestCase`.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the problem of verification that all required signals are connected.
Thank you for all your comments. As the result there is available [SignalConnectionTestCase](https://github.com/zakamarek/django-test-signals) which is based on introspection (as it was proposed by @frank-t) and for built-in signals the solution of initial problem can be done as follows:

```
class SignalsTest(SignalConnectionTestCase):
    expected_post_save = ['publisher.signals.receiver_function']
```

For own signals you can just call [`verify`](https://github.com/zakamarek/django-test-signals/blob/850eee692de8f5ef7aa85c3ef8d098d60871881a/django_test_signals/signalconnectiontestcase.py#L46) function in your test method.